# performance testing using jmeter cross checking the response with web data does not match

Tags: jmeter

I have a web service URL:
https://app.snapmed.no/landing-page?flow=chat
The response code is 200 and the response body does not contain any valid data to cross-check with the webpage response or data in chrome  It is completely dynamic. Now I do not know a [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p5vd.png)way to add response assertion for this type of response. can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't have to use assertions, as per [Reducing resource requirements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean) chapter of [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

> - Use as few Assertions as possible

JMeter automatically checks [HTTP Response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) and marks the HTTP Request sampler as failed if response code is 400 or higher.

If you want to add an extra layer of check you can explicitly validate that the page returns the HTTP Status Code 200 as follows:

[image]

also as far as I can see the web page always contains `Send bilder til hudlege` text so you can validate it as well:

[image]

More information: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps)

Comment: can add a **picture** of your http request? my viewresult tree is just showing parent httprequest node and it does not have any child nodes

Comment: I think you need to tick "retrieve all embedded resources" box, the setting is under "Advanced" tab of the HTTP Request Sampler (or [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults)). More information: [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses)